# Copy blob fails in azurite, works in azure blob storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azurite

Why does this operation work copying a blob to azure storage:

```
az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $blob.name --destination-container $containerName --connection-string $destConnectionString --source-account-name "$sourceStorageAccount" --source-account-key "$sourceStorageKey" --source-container $containerName --source-blob $blob.name --auth-mode key
```

but fails when copying to azurite. The connection string for azurite is:

```
$destConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;"
```

I am using powershell 5. The error message is:

> ERROR: The specified resource does not exist
> At D:\Work\GlobalBridge Docs\Move Blobs.ps1:53 char:13
> az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $blob.name  ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The spec... does not exist:String) [], RemoteException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
> RequestId:4d10d763-77e3-42b7-b1f0-5b7bb8e8940d
> Time:2023-06-16T13:37:14.025Z
> ErrorCode:CannotVerifyCopySource

However, the copy source exists. I am using azurite 3.24.0. The connection string works for other operations such as "az storage container create"